# Trying to store range slider value in a cookie

Tags: javascript, html, cookies

I have html range sliders on a page, and I want to store the value to a cookie when a user moves the slider, so that the slider will automatically be set to what they selected when they come back again.

I am very new to javascript (know the bare basics). So I followed this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VqzSex_2tDc

Firstly... in that tutorial the guy added "onchange="setMyCookie()" to an html dropdown box. So that the dropdown would automatically show the cookie value. However, I am not using a dropdown, I'm using an html range slider. So can I add "onchange="setMyCookie()" directly to a range slider? Like so, see below - Is that wrong?

```
<input type="range" id="loan" name="loan" min="5000" max="500000" step="5000" onchange="setLoanCookie()">
```

I noticed other tutorials ads it to a submit button. Can I store values of range sliders to a cookie without requiring the user to click submit first?

After following the tutorial... this is what I have.... is this close to right? Or am I far off... what am I doing wrong because it's not working?

Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function ()
{
    if (document.cookie.length != 0)
    {
        var nameValueArray = document.cookie.split("=");
        document.getElementById("loan").value = nameValueArray[1];
    }
}

function setLoanCookie()
{
    var selectedLoan = document.getElementById("loan").value;
    document.cookie = "mloan=" + selectedLoan +
                        ";expires=Fri, 5 Dec 2016 01:00:00 UTC;";
}
</script>
```

HTML:

```
<input type="range" id="loan" name="loan" min="5000" max="500000" step="5000" onchange="setLoanCookie()">
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTML5 Slider with onchange function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13896685/html5-slider-with-onchange-function)

Comment: I tossed all your code into a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4mk5mrqk/) and it seems to work fine...