# Return value from html to django with range input every time its value changes

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I have a project that **takes a value from my website** (django framework) and pass it back to django so that it can be used to run some scripts in case to dim the lights of my house (IOT project).
I've found this code in django docs tha does this by a submit button but in my case it would be better with range input.  What i exactly am looking for is to send the value back every time the slider changes position just like when i press submit button.Thanks in advance.

here my code.html file

```
{% extends "personal/header.html" %}

{% block content %}

<form action="/code/" method="post">

{% csrf_token %}
{{ form}}
<input type="submit" value="Submit"  /> 

</form>

{% endblock %}
```

And this is on my views

```
def get_name(request):
# if this is a POST request we need to process the form data
if request.method == 'POST':
    # create a form instance and populate it with data from the request:
    form = NameForm(request.POST)
    # check whether it's valid:
    if form.is_valid():
        # process the data in form.cleaned_data as required
        # ...
        # redirect to a new URL:
        print(form['your_name']) # outputs for example : <input type="text" name="your_name" value="34" required id="id_your_name" /> I would like to know how to print just its value :)

        return HttpResponseRedirect('/code/')

# if a GET (or any other method) we'll create a blank form
else:
    form = NameForm()

return render(request, 'personal/code.html', {'form': form})
```

And this is the forms.py file

```
from django import forms

class NameForm(forms.Form):
your_name = forms.DurationField(label='% Brightness ')
```

[Here is a picture of the working code tha i want to ***replace with a range*** input instead of ***submit***](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e4CZt.png)

[For example something like this(Range input pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tbhgi.png)

Also this is what is happening to django (python manage.py runserver) when i submit for example the value of *345* (django shell)
htt//a//ps://i.stack.imgur.com/0fMtG.png **(remove the //a//)**

Comment: You will want to remove the button and execute an ajax request every time the slider has move to a different position

Comment: Do you mean : <input type="range" name="rangeInput" min="0" max="100"   value= '' method="POST" onchange="AjaxRequest(this.value);"> Somethink like this? May you can give me a link with "how to use ajax"?

Comment: You best [add a listener to your on change event](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13896685/html5-slider-with-onchange-function) of the slider, and in that function you [execute your ajax call (using jQuery for instance)](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/).

Comment: Thanks for the quick answers-help @dentemm