# How do you dynamically transfer data between Python-code and HTML

Tags: python, html, flask

My goal is an interactive `html` with a `Python`-code on the backend. In the basis, the `html`-page will contain a couple of sliders, and their values will be used as input for a `Python`-based code to returns some value(s) back to the `html`-page to present.

Nothing fancy, I thought. However... I want that the value of the slider is send to the `Python`-code immediately, and the `Python`-code "immediately" sends back its output ("immediately" = ASAP). For some reason, I get one of the following two working, but not both:

1. The slider's value is updated immediately and its value is presented on screen. Simultaneously, I can see that the correct `Python`-method is called, but no data is transferred.
2. The slider's value is submitted to the `Python`-code and its output is returned to the `html`-page, but it requires a click on a `submit`-button.

MWE:

**`html`-page:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Estimate</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form method="POST">
        <div class="rangeslider">
            <input type="range" name="var1" min="0" max="10" value="5" class="myslider" id="slider1">
            <p>
                Var. 1: <span id="out1"></span>
            </p>
        </div>

        <script>
            const Http = new XMLHttpRequest();
            var slide1 = document.getElementById("slider1");
            var out1 = document.getElementById("out1");

            slider1.oninput = function() {
                out1.innerHTML = this.value;

                Http.open('POST', '/output')
                Http.send(out1)
            }
        </script>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**`Python`-backend:**

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/')
def base():
    return render_template('estimate.html', var1=5)


@app.route('/output', methods=['POST'])
def update():
    # var1 = request.form['var1']
    data = request.form  # results in an empty dict: `ImmutableMultiDict([])`
    var1 = 5  # so the return-statement does not break
    print(data)  # I know that this method is called, as `data` (empty dict) is printed when I change the sliders value
    return render_template('estimate.html', var1=var1, output=f'Output\nVariable 1 = {var1}')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

I do know about the option of `onchange` in the `html`-slider, but have not got it working.

I am quiet new to `html` and do not know much about `JavaScript`; I am more familiar with `Python`.

Hopefully anyone can help me out! I have searched around quiet a lot already, but have not found an answer to my issue.

If it matters: I am using Python 3.7, and use `flask` as framework.

Answer (score 1):

[Turbo Flask](https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/dynamically-update-your-flask-web-pages-using-turbo-flask) is what you need.

```sh
(venv) $ pip install flask turbo-flask
```

[Github](https://github.com/miguelgrinberg/turbo-flask) link here.

Answer (score 0):

1. I think it makes sense to call your server when the slide value changes (onchange event). See this [Stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13896745/15211203) on how to use a slider's onchange event.
2. In your python code, you are doing `request.form['var1']` but you did not post your form (per your code, you only sent a specific variable). I think you have the following options

   a. Send the entire form. See [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Forms/Sending_forms_through_JavaScript) for different ways you can do this

   b. Send just the data for the input field. To do this, you'll have to create a parameter for it. Something like

   ```
   var params = {"var1" : document.getElementById("out1").value};

   // Send the param
   HTTP.send(params)

   # Receive it in your python code as
   request.values.get("var1")
   ```
3. If you're sending just a single variable and it is not of a large size and you are doing an asynchronous call (which means user never sees your url on their browser), you can actually make this a `GET` call and not a `POST` call

Answer (score 0):

Use *fetch* requests, to perform ajax requests without using a form submit.

Following into your *html*, remove **rangeslider** out of the form body and change *script* to this:

```
<div class="rangeslider">
        <input type="range" name="var1" min="0" max="10" value="5" class="myslider" id="slider1">
        <p>
            Var. 1: <span id="out1"></span>
        </p>
    </div>

    <script>

      var slide1 = document.getElementById("slider1");
      var out1 = document.getElementById("out1");

      slider1.oninput = function() {
        fetch('/slider/'+this.value).then(function(response){
          response.json().then(function(data){
          out1.innerHTML = data.value
          })
        })
      }
  </script>
```

Then in your back-end, add this to your routes

```
@app.route('/slider/<value>',methods = ['GET','POST'])
def slider(value):
    return jsonify({'value': value})
```

*P.S you will need Jquery to perform ajax requests, so add it to your HTML head*